# How to get livestream chat messages from YouTube? It looks like it's broken

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I read the documentation page very attentively, but it won't work.

I'm trying to fetch posts from a stream, but I keep getting an error that the `pageToken` is invalid. Although this parameter is optional and can only be obtained after receiving a list of messages.

[Documentation page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list)

It is not working even on documentation page. To check - you can use `4xDzrJKXOOY` id. Here is query:

```bash
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=4xDzrJKXOOY&part=snippet&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS TOKEN' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

And here's what I get:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "page token is not valid.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "page token is not valid.",
        "domain": "youtube.liveChat",
        "reason": "pageTokenInvalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Video id is absolutely valid, you can check it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xDzrJKXOOY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`liveChatId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list#liveChatId) is incorrect, you should use the value [`activeLiveChatId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.activeLiveChatId) returned by [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with [`part=liveStreamingDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part).

In your case it would be `Cg0KCzR4RHpySktYT09ZKicKGFVDU0o0Z2tWQzZOcnZJSTh1bXp0ZjBPdxILNHhEenJKS1hPT1k` and retrieving the associated messages with:

[https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=Cg0KCzR4RHpySktYT09ZKicKGFVDU0o0Z2tWQzZOcnZJSTh1bXp0ZjBPdxILNH&part=snippet&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=Cg0KCzR4RHpySktYT09ZKicKGFVDU0o0Z2tWQzZOcnZJSTh1bXp0ZjBPdxILNH&part=snippet&key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D)

works fine.